# Alternative way to generate google oauth yaml?

Tags: ruby, oauth, yaml

Following instructions on [this page](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/instantiate) by Google's Oauth for API access guide. It requires that I run a terminal command to generate a yaml to be used for Oauth. However, the command no longer runs. The gem has removed the functionality, and I tried using the previous version of the gem, but there are conflicting versions in the gem dependencies which keep it from running. Any ideas on how I could generate this yaml file another way? I know how to download the json file with my client_id, can I simply conver the json to a yaml?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I might stick to the newer version of the Gem (for stability reasons), and just do the conversion yourself. I've had success with the JSON-YAML conversion with this, using both the JSON and YAML modules:

```
require 'json'
require 'yaml'

json = '{ "boo": "bop" }'
data = JSON.parse(json)
yml = YAML::dump(data)
```